# MMDC not found in mermaid.cli

Tags: mermaid

I tried to use [gatsby-remark-draw](https://github.com/rhanekom/gatsby-remark-draw) to render mermaid diagrams which includes installing `mermaid` and `mermaid.cli`. However, the diagram becomes code blocks instead, even though I followed the instruction of putting this plugin before the `gatsby-remark-prismjs` in the config. And I kept on getting this error:

```
Unhandled exception in rendering: Error: Unable to render graph language with mermaid:      
Error: not found: mmdc
```

Comment: What do you mean by "which includes installing `mermaid` and `mermaid.cli`"? Those are only `devDependencies` so they probably won't get installed automatically for you. [The instructions](https://github.com/rhanekom/gatsby-remark-draw#mermaid) tell you to install them yourself. Did you do that?

Comment: Yes, I did install them as per the instructions. Actually, I found a way by installing the `mermaid.cli` globally and then the diagrams finally worked. I really don't know how that happened.